# Взаимодействие процессов

Tags: c

Помогите,пожалуйста,найти ошибку.
Программа получает через аргумента командной строки имя файла. Надо запустить программу `grep` с параметром `int` и потоком ввода, перенаправленным на ввод из заданного файла.
Пробую в качестве имя файла подать файл в котором находится текст моей программы, а программа ничего кроме `Done` не выдает.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int fd[2],file;
    pipe(fd);
    if(fork()==0){
        dup2(fd[0],0);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execlp("grep","grep","int",NULL);
        perror("WTF!?");
        exit(1);
    }
    file=open(argv[1],O_RDWR);
    dup2(fd[1],file);
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    close(file);
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данной задаче `pipe` вообще не нужен. (Вы почему-то взяли за основу код своего предыдущего вопроса и совершенно неправильно его модифицировали).

А тут нужно создать новый процесс, в котором перед запуском `grep` надо открыть файл и сдублировать его дескриптор в дескриптор стандартного ввода (попросту, дапнуть файл на stdin), из коего grep и будет читать.

В родительском же процессе, ничего кроме wait, делать вообще не надо.

На всякий случай пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  if (ac != 2)
    errx(EX_USAGE, "Usage:  file");
  pid_t p = fork();

  if (p == -1)
    err(EX_OSERR, "fork");
  else if (p == 0) {
    int file = open(av[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (file < 0)
      err(EX_NOINPUT, "open %s", av[1]);
    dup2(file, 0);
    close(file);  // можно и не делать, grep-у дескрипторов хватит
    execlp("grep", "grep", "int", NULL);
    err(EX_OSERR, "exec grep");
  }
  wait(0);

  return puts("End") == EOF; 
}
```

Рекомендую почитать ман-ы (и из разделов SEE ALSO тоже) для каждой функции (а также, для нормального освоения системы, можно и файлы в `#include` тоже посмотреть).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь много ошибок.

Как минимум, следующий код:

```
file=open(argv[1],O_RDWR);
dup2(fd[1],file);
```

открывает и тут же закрывает file. Вероятно, имелось в виду `dup2(file, fd[1])`.

P.S.

- В целом, dup2 устаревший вызов. Его функции может выполнить fcntl
- Стоит расставить assert, чтобы в каком конкретном месте возникает проблема